# TFS Custom Build Template - TfsBuild reference

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

On the imports tab of my custom build template (xaml) I managed to get all of the imports resolved except for one that just says TfsBuild. Does anyone know where I can add this reference from?

Comment: Was that a reference from TFS 2008?

Comment: No its TFS2010. It doesn't seem to be causing any problems but it has a red mark next to it (meaning not resolved). This is in the Imports for my custom xaml build template.

Comment: Where it came from? does it have a fully qualified name or just 'TfsBuild'?

Comment: If I knew that I wouldn't have posted. I can't find anything in the XAML or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I was noticing the "TfsBuild" unresolved reference in my custom builds after upgrading to TFS 2012.  I ended up replacing it with Template.TfsBuild.

Comment: This was before upgrading. I have it resolved now but it has been so long I don't recall what I did to fix it. I think it was just something with references or not having service pack or something installed.